# How to create index for jsonb key existence?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

Currently I'm doing this:

```sql
CREATE INDEX bla ON table1((LENGTH(data->>'programs') > 0))
```

for the query:

```sql
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT p AS prog
FROM Clients c, jsonb_array_elements(c.data->'programs') p
WHERE LENGTH(c.data->>'programs') > 0
  AND (p->>'token') = '';
-- because jsonb_array_elements can only for non null
```

That index doesn't work, it still doing manual scan

```
Nested Loop  (cost=0.01..56.19 rows=27 width=32) (actual time=6.284..6.285 rows=0 loops=1)
  ->  Seq Scan on clients c  (cost=0.00..15.42 rows=27 width=566) (actual time=0.099..5.214 rows=50 loops=1)
        Filter: (length((data ->> 'programs'::text)) > 0)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 31
  ->  Function Scan on jsonb_array_elements p  (cost=0.01..1.50 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.021..0.021 rows=0 loops=50)
        Filter: ((value ->> 'token'::text) = ''::text)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 7
Planning Time: 0.079 ms
Execution Time: 6.423 ms
```

Note: I didn't design this table .__.)/|| if I'm the one that designed it, I would not ever use array of object inside JSONB.

Comment: Your table appears to be very small.  Do you take an Uber to get from your bedroom to your kitchen?

Comment: ah you have good point, lemme just ignore it then XD hopefully it won't grow big or another table doesn't do something like this

Comment: If `programs` is a  JSON array, then `length(data->>'programs')` doesn't make sense. You probably want `jsonb_array_length(data -> 'programs')` . And if you want to test if the programs array contains at least one element where `token = ""` you can do that more efficiently using `data @> '{"programs": [{"token": ""}]}` - but without more details on how your JSON is structure and what the underlying problem is that you are trying to solve, this can't really be answered.

Comment: too bad got similar error `cannot get array length of scalar` if using `jsonb_array_length` because that value can be null